# Reading from a file with f.readline() reads more lines than the real file has

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I'm trying to make a sorting function to order words by length, so the first step is finding the longest word.

In order to do this I've produced the following code, it works as intended, but there's a bug that caught my attention and I'm trying to figure out what causes it.

After replacing a word, the buffer will always read the next line as if it was empty, but will eventually reach the next word, but will testify the reading was done in the wrong line.

```
def sort():
    f = open("source.txt","r")
    w = open("result.txt","a+")
    word = ''
    og_lines = sum(1 for line in open('source.txt'))
    print("Sorting",og_lines,"words...")
    new_lines = 1
    lenght = 0
    word = f.readline(new_lines)
    new_lines+=1
    buffer=f.readline(new_lines)
    while (buffer != ''):
        if (len(buffer)>len(word)):
            word=buffer
            print("change")
        new_lines+=1
        print(new_lines, "lines read")
        buffer=f.readline(new_lines)
        buffer.rstrip()
    lenght = len(word.rstrip())
    print("Longest word is",word.rstrip(),lenght)
```

Expected to read 25 lines, but since it found a longer word 4 times along the way, it ended up reading the nonexistent line 29 and yet returning the word from the real line 25.

Comment: The parameter to `.readline()` is a maximum length, NOT the line number to be read.  So you are forcing some of your earlier lines to be split up, because they're longer than the number you're passing at that point.  Normally you wouldn't use any parameter with this method.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, it's working now.